# Trouble Installing Specific Version of Ruby (OpenSSL Issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, macos-sonoma

I have a 2020 Intel Mac running Sonoma. I'm working on a web app project that is running on Rails. For the last few months, I've had the same issue no matter what I try. I follow the Rails instructions on their website but I keep running into OpenSSL errors. I've tried asdf, rvm, and rbenv for package managers and am trying to install Ruby 3.0.4, which is what the app runs on.

I keep getting a error that looks something like this:

```
*** Following extensions are not compiled:
openssl:
    Could not be configured. It will not be installed.
```

I've tried downloading and redownloading OpenSSL, trying different versions, and changing my paths accordingly, as well as changing flags and other things. However, I can't seem to make this work on my machine. I eventually got it working on a Oracle VirtualBox, but I'd prefer to have it just running on my Mac.

Anyone have any idea or solutions. I've seen a lot of posts regarding this on different websites, so it seems to be an issue with a lot of people, but nothing is working for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby 3.0 requires OpenSSL version 1.1, which is quite old now and unsupported on a lot of environments. It is advised that you upgrade the app to run on at least Ruby 3.1, which uses modern OpenSSL version.

That said on OSX you can still get this running, using `homebrew`, `rbenv` and `ruby-build`. Note, that the guide will use `rbenv` as the ruby manager, if you use something else (like `rvm`) then you'll need to change some of the guide to cater for that. (Or uninstall that and swap to `rbenv`)

Do note that the guide below will install ruby 3.0.6 and not 3.0.4. You should probably move tho this version as this is the latest of the 3.0.x branches, which should still not break your existing app.

Also note that the steps below should also work with ruby 2.7 if needed. and we had some success with 2.6, but there were some other steps needed to get it running that I don't remember.

1. Make sure you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed. Should be standard if you do development on a Mac though.
2. Assuming you don't have a ruby manager installed yet install and set up `rbenv`:

```bash
brew install rbenv

if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
  SHELL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH=~/.zshrc
elif [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  SHELL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH=~/.bashrc
else
  SHELL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH=~/.profile
fi

echo "eval '$(rbenv init -)'" >> $SHELL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH
echo "export PATH='$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH'" >> $SHELL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH
source $SHELL_CONFIG_FILE_PATH
```

If you use something else like `rvm` or `chruby` then you can skip the above, although note that `ruby-build` works best with `rbenv`.

3. Install `ruby-build`:

```bash
brew install ruby-build
```

4. Install openssl 1.1:

```bash
brew install openssl@1.1
```

5. Install ruby with the proper openssl version:

```bash
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"
rbenv install 3.0.6
```

Note, if you don't use `rbenv` then you have to use ruby-build natively:

```bash
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"
ruby-build 3.0.6 /opt/rubies/3.0.6
```

and then configure your other ruby manager to point to this version of ruby.

6. Set up some symlinks (Optional, but needed by some gems. Only do this if you encounter issues otherwise as it can break apps running on newer openssl versions):

For Intel mac or Homebrew running under Rosetta:

```bash
ln -sf /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
ln -sf /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib
```

For ARM mac:

```bash
ln -sf /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
ln -sf /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib
```

7. Manually install the `openssl` gem for your ruby:

```bash
rbenv local 3.0.6

gem install openssl -v '2.2.3' -- --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)
```

(do this for every `openssl` gem version that's in your bundle file)

8. Issues with gems.

Some gems might need to be linked to a different openssl, if that's the case you might use the below. For example we had issues with `puma` and `eventmachine`:

```bash
brew install openssl@3 openssl

bundle config set --global build.eventmachine --with-ssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)
bundle config set --global build.puma --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)
```

These steps should get you through, and still work as of January 2024, on Sonoma for both Intel and ARM macs.

Also if you need to install a newer ruby while keeping support for 3.0.6 you should then use:

```bash
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)"

rbenv install 3.1.4
# works with 3.2 and 3.3 as well
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. Initially I got it to work and `ruby -v` and `which -a ruby` would point to the version I want. Today, however, it seems that it is pointing to `ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin23]`. I have `rbenv` installed and everything looks right, but `rbenv` won't show up at all for `which -a ruby`, however it does in my `$PATH`. `3.0.4` will show up in my `rbenv versions` and `rbenv local` and `rbenv global`. Any ideas?

Comment: @carmenalexander check your $PATH, rbenv should be there. Also make sure you don't have rvm installed. You can always run `rbenv init` to get some instructions on how to install it